# Importing Maven Project from SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have imported a Maven project from SVN developed by another user. After checking out it is showing problems for jar files pointing to other user profile. Isn't Maven supposed to manage the dependencies to avoid these problems?

Comment: It would help greatly if you posted the pom.xml here so we can see relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

This process helps me usually:

**Right click the project-Run As-Run Configuration**- then in goal write **eclipse:clean** and click **run**. after cleaning, run **eclipse:eclipse**. it will take some time to download the dependencies.After that **run update the project** from **maven** option.

Comment: I have 4 projects in SVN which are inter-dependent and among them only 1 project is having pom.xml.. So i assume that this maven project controls all the 4 projects dependencies. Do i need to do your procedure for every project ?

Comment: you have to follow above process which has pom.xml file

Comment: When i am checking out from SVN , Is there any special process to follow to check out this Maven project ?